# implement segment button using html, css and bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I need to implement a [segment button](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/segment) using only HTML, CSS and bootstrap as shown in the below picture. many people confuse between toggle and segment buttons. toggle-button toggles between on-click but the segment button can have multiple buttons and will toggle only on clicking the particular button. In my case, I need to implement only 2 buttons within 1 segment button. if my statement confuses, please follow the link and there is an example. any help is appreciated. thank you.
[image: segment button]

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap, this feature is called "Button-Group", check this Reference: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/button-group/

You can style your Button-Group as you desire - if you want to e.g. put icons in it, just replace the text in the example ("left/middle/right") with an icon

Comment: I have checked it but I need more similar to what I mentioned above.

Comment: What do you mean by "more similar"? It is exactly the same functionality - what part are you missing?